# Hide Duplicates Based On Criteria

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with 2 columns:

| Product | Received |
| --- | --- |
| a | 01-01-2022 |
| a |  |
| b |  |
| c | 20-01-2022 |
| c |  |
| d |  |

I need to create a query that will hide duplicates on the "Product" column, if there´s aleready a record that contains that procuct and also a date in the "Recieved" column.

To get this result:

| Product | Received |
| --- | --- |
| b |  |
| d |  |

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query using GROUP BY and testing the condition in the HAVING clause, i.e., after grouping

```sql
SELECT prod.Product, Max(prod.Received) AS MaxOfReceived, count(*) as cnt
FROM prod
GROUP BY prod.Product
HAVING Max(prod.Received) Is Null OR count(*) = 1;
```

It lists all products either having no `Received` date or having only one record.